# I plant 3 red trees, 4 blue trees, and 5 green trees in a row randomly. Find the probability that no 2 green trees are next to each other

Tags: probability

I am not sure how to start, as casework seems to take too long and finding each individual probability is also difficult due to the number of trees.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{7}{3}$ sequences of $3$ red and $4$ blue trees since choosing the positions of the red trees completely determines the positions of the blue trees.  Each such sequence creates eight spaces in which we can insert a green tree.  For instance, if we are working with the sequence $RBBBRRB$, 
$$\square R \square B \square B \square B \square R \square R \square B \square$$
To separate the green trees, we must choose five of these eight spaces in which to insert a green tree, which we do in $\binom{8}{5}$ ways.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is 
$$\binom{7}{3}\binom{8}{5}$$
The total number of sequences of $3$ red, $4$ blue, and $5$ green trees is 
$$\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{4}\binom{5}{5}$$
where we choose three of the $12$ positions for the red trees, four of the remaining nine positions for the blue trees, and fill the remaining five positions with the green trees.  Hence, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{7}{3}\dbinom{8}{5}}{\dbinom{12}{3}\dbinom{9}{4}\dbinom{5}{5}}$$

Answer (score -1):

First of all, we can reduce this down to 5 green trees and 7 blue trees, as the distinction between red and blue doesn't matter. Now given 12 spots, we want to place 5 green trees in these spots so that none are next to each other. We can just place 5 green trees in 11 spots arbitrarily, then add a space in between the green trees, so the total count is $\binom{11}{5}$. There are $\binom{12}{5}$ ways to plant the trees, so the probability is $\frac{\binom{11}{5}}{\binom{12}{5}}=\frac{7}{12}$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  The distinction between red and blue does matter.  For the favorable cases, we need to insert green trees into sequences of red and blue trees in such a way that no two of the green trees are adjacent.  Also, the denominator is the number of possible sequences of three red, four blue, and five green trees.